# How to select column name in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy/update data from Table A to Table B.  Table B has some more additional columns. I have tried the following options.

```
1) `REPLACE INTO `B` (SHOW FIELDS FROM 'A') SELECT * FROM `A

2) `REPLACE INTO `B` 
     (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
              WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test1' AND `TABLE_NAME`='A') SELECT * FROM `A
```

But it throws errors. Can you guys help me how to select names with select query?

**UPDATE:**

3) As suggested by Jerko,

I have two tables A(warehouse_id,long,lat)  B(warehouse_id,long)

Applied the following statement.

```
SET @query = CONCAT('REPLACE INTO `A` (SELECT  ', 
                     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',column_name, '`')) 
                      FROM information_schema.columns 
                      WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test2' AND `table_name` = 'A'), 
                   ' FROM  `B`)');


PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This gives me the error

> "#1054 - Unknown column 'lat' in 'field list' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a way

```
SET @query = CONCAT('REPLACE INTO `A` (', 
                  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',column_name, '`')) 
                  FROM information_schema.columns 
                  WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test1' AND `table_name` = 'A'
                  AND column_name IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'test1' AND table_name='B')) ,
                  ') (SELECT  ', 
                 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',column_name, '`')) 
                  FROM information_schema.columns 
                  WHERE  `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test1' AND `table_name` = 'A'
                  AND column_name IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'test1' AND table_name='B')), 
               ' FROM  `B`)');


PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: thanks, but its throwing the error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 ".  Am I missing something from above query? Coz I have never used prepared statements before

Comment: maybe you are giving it wrong table_schema and table name?

Comment: yes its definitely this because I put wrong table_schema name and it's throwing same error

Comment: Oh yes it was my fault, I apologise. This sounds good solution, but again I am getting wrong column error

Comment: FIRST make sure inner SELECT works, then make sure you have all columns from table B in table A, also post error here, we will debug it

Comment: Hi Jerko, looking at it. Will let you know

Comment: Hi Jerko, I tried your solution however it gives me error. See my updated question

Comment: it mean you don't have `lat` field in your `B` table, just add `AND column_name != 'lat'` in your `WHERE` clause or add empty `lat` field in your `B` table

Comment: Thanks Jerko, But there are several tables such like that. It will take a lot of time if I add columns explicitly like this. I did not want to mention column name thats why I wrote  queries in options 1,2

Comment: Ok sure, you gave almost 90% solution. Something is missing that I cant figure it out

Comment: A gem. Worked like a charm. That is the solution. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this dynamically in mysql like you are trying to do. MySQL expects your list of column names to be provided directly, not from a subquery.

If you want to do this dynamically you'll have to step back upstream to whatever language you are using to interact with MySQL such as PHP or Java.

Comment: its necessary to provide field names?

Comment: Using another language like PHP you can first query the table structure to get the column names and then use that to build the second query.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi - absolutely, yes.  Think about this; if it was automatic, can you imagine the _wonderful_ avenues for SQL Injection?  There'd be essentially no defense - prepared statements wouldn't do any good, because they're at the wrong level.  So no sane RDBMS will do auto-expansion for you...  not that it'd be able to distinguish between regular data and column names anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
insert into B(col1, . . ., coln)
    select col1, . . ., coln
    from A;
```

That is, list the fields from `A` in the `select` clause.  List the corresponding columns for `B` in the `insert` column list.

If you need the list of columns, get them from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and cut-and-paste into the query.

Comment: Obviously this will work. But I want to select column names as select statements

Comment: You can only do that with dynamic SQL, using a `prepare` statement.  And even then, you would have to be 100% sure that the column names are the same in both tables, a condition that your question does not mention.

Comment: The other table has some more columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO B (field1,field2,...,fieldN) 
        SELECT (field1,field2,...,fieldN) FROM A
```

Comment: Thanks but I need fields as subquery